# R Nested For Loop for a Sensitivity Analysis

Tags: r, for-loop, nested, time-series

I'm fairly new to R and I've been trying for a while to do something, which I assumed to be very simple, but I keep failing at it (unfortunately for me, it doesn't mean it's not simple!).

I have defined a function that takes a time series as an input and outputs a single value (as a vector) at the end. The function has two parameters (from now on **n** and **m**) affecting the output, so it looks like this:

```
fnc <- function(x, n, m)
```

My goal is to store/see (possibly in a matrix?) the output while changing **n** and **m** (so, a basic sensitivity analysis, if this makes sense?).

My attempts were to create an empty matrix, run a nested for loop for several n and m values and fill in the matrix accordingly.

So, something like this *(I'm aware that the code below gives an error, as i,j values would end up being out of bounds the 3x3 matrix, but it is just one of the illogical-trial I did)*:

```
n_lens = c(750, 1000, 1250)
m_lens = c(250, 300, 350)

output_matrix = matrix(data=NA, nrow = length(n_lens), ncol = length(m_lens))

for (i in n_lens){
  for (j in m_lens){
        output_matrix[i,j] <- function(x, i, j)
      }  
    }
```

Unfortunately all of them were far from getting the job done.

Any suggestion/tip is much appreciated.

Comment: Thank you very much, it does work perfectly. As you correctly anticipated it's a bit slow, any heads up regarding the othe rways to accomplish this in R?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I  took the freedom to define a simple fnc function.
The idea is to loop over the indices of n_lens and not on the values of n_lens.
Nested for loops may be (will be?) slower in R compared to other ways of R.

It produces the required output.

```
fnc <- function(x, n, m)
{ 
  return (n+m)
}

n_lens = c(750, 1000, 1250)
m_lens = c(250, 300, 350)
x = 1

len_n = length(n_lens)
len_m = length(m_lens)
output_matrix = matrix(data=NA, nrow = length(n_lens), ncol = length(m_lens))

for (i in seq(len_n)){
  for (j in seq(len_m)){
    output_matrix[i,j] <- fnc(x, n_lens[i], m_lens[j])
  }  
}
output_matrix
```

The output received is

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,] 1000 1050 1100
[2,] 1250 1300 1350
[3,] 1500 1550 1600
```